# trying to encrypt & decrypt password in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Hi  want to encrypt the password before sending it in httpost method.
in my view section i am capturing password and sending in controller section at httppost
i want to encrypt password before sending it in httppost method and at Post section i want to decrypt
the password before sending it to a service for authentication.
View

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
 {
  <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
  @Html.Password("txtBxPassword", null, new { @class = "form-control" })
  </div>
}
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(FormCollection form)
{
string msg= oService.GenericIsAuthenticatedWithMessage("ABC", form["txtBxUsername"].ToString().Trim().ToUpper(), form["txtBxPassword"].ToString());
}
```

Comment: Did you try writing any code for this? What issues you are facing in that? Why you want to do encryption and decryption of password this way?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya i have seen seen in net all are doing in server side  and i am not aware how to do it in mvc .i want to encrypt in client side and while retriving decrypt in post method..

Comment: In javascript you can use btoa method to encode password. refer - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Base64 and on server side - you need to decode it again before passing actual password for authentication. here is code -                                                                                                   byte[] data =System.Convert.FromBase64String(input.Password); input.Password = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(data); this is simple way to hide actual password in request

Answer (score 0):

before posting encrypt you password by converting into base64 and decrypt on server side from base64 to string